# What's the most common usage and meaning of the verb исходить, which belongs to two impf/pf verb pairs, each with a different meaning?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, вид

According to a table of frequency I found, the verb **исходить** ranks pretty high (1716 out of 100,000). However, since it has two usages and meanings, I wonder which one is most frequently used:

- in the pair исходить/изойти (to go out of, to emanate, to be based upon), where it's imperfective;
- or in the pair исхаживать/исходить (to go everywhere), where it's perfective?

Could someone give me some examples for both cases, along with any trick to determine it's meaning in any given text or conversation?

Comment: Oh my, these are the words of waaay too many multilateral usages. "Исходить пол-России" to cover half-of-the-Russia on foot, "исход евреев из Египта" the exodus of Jews from Egypt, "изойти на говно" to throw one long and the worst possible tantrum, not to mention "исходящие документы" outgoing documents, outbox, or "исходный код" source code. You see - this ain't that straightforward to compare semantically.

Comment: "изойти на говно" does not exist in the normal Russian, this is slang. "Изойти слюной" - completely normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is definitely the more frequent one.

The latter is a tricky special usage of **из-** whose meaning is "to ______ all over", which is always perfective-forming and, I think, no longer productive in modern Russian (replaced by a similar usage of **за-**). **Исходить пол-России** is a very good example from the comments; it has the semantics of metaphorically covering half of Russia in "having walked there", as on a colouring map: same basic idea as in **изрисовать** "to draw all over, cover in doodles" and even **избить**.

That, however, is a fairly rare usage of **исходить**; even for that exact concept, you're more likely to come across a synonymous use of **обойти**. So you're not all that likely to ever have to tell which is which. Supposing you do, though, the trick is very simple: the "go out" one is intransitive (**исходить из** + genitive) and the "walk everywhere in" one is transitive (**исходить** + accusative).

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay Ershov. Would you have a link to a resource that explicits that из-, when meaning "to ______ all over" is always perfective-forming ?

Comment: Это вот папаша прежде все леса вдоль и поперек исхаживал. [Н. П. Колпакова. Терский берег (1936)]

Answer (score 2):

I will give three examples of most frequently used meanings (IMHO), not mentioning phraseological units

1. Запах супа исходил из его кухни. (come from)
   (Intransitive)
2. Он исходил все улочки, все площади средневекового центра (wander over)
   (transitive)
3. Платон исходил из сократовской трактовки соотношения языка и мышления, языка и вещи.
   Закон исходил из того, что свидетелем может быть любое лицо, которому могут быть известны какие-либо обстоятельства, относящиеся к делу .(proceed from the assumption)
   (Intransitive)